# How to align wrapfigures (not sub-figures) vertically one above the other?

Tags: align

I want to align wrap figures (not sub-figures) vertically one above the other, how can I do that?

This is the part of LaTex code where I have this issue:

```
 \section{Matériaux Flexibles}

 \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
 \vspace{-20pt}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{silicon.jpg}

\caption{silicone}
 \end{wrapfigure}


 Un matériau est dit flexible s'il se déforme sous l'action d'une force extérieur 
 tel que: le silicone (figure 3.1), le caoutchouc et certains matériaux plastiques.

 La flexibilité de ces matériaux permettent des nouvelles applications dans      différents domaines, notamment, la robotique et l'interface utilisateur.\\

 \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{snake.jpg}
    \caption{silicone}
 \end{wrapfigure}
 L'introduction des robots issues des matériaux douces et flexibles a augmenté la      chance de leurs utilisation dans les applications où il y a nécessité d'interaction      directe avec l'homme, par exemple: dans le domaine médicale pour la chirurgie et      l'interaction avec les malades (figure 3.2). De plus, ces matériaux ont joué un rôle majeur dans le développement de la biomimétisme, permettant ainsi des mouvements complexes qui ne sont pas possible à réaliser avec les robots rigides.

 \section{Retour Haptique}
```

Comment: Can you please complete your code snipet to a compilable minimal working code that we can copy to our computers to test it and to play with it to help you?  BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both `\includegraphics` inside the same `wrapfigure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
 \section{A section}
 \begin{wrapfigure}[18]{r}{0.3\textwidth}
 \vspace{-20pt}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{silicone}
    \vspace{1em}
   \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{silicone}
 \end{wrapfigure}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibu-
lum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne-
tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus
rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu
tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-
abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum.Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse
ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna.
Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes:

1. Add enough content in the paragraph atteched to `wrapfigure`
2. Use the optional argument (`[18]` here) in `\begin{wrapfigure}[18]{r}` to fix the number of lines that break.
3. Adjust `\vspace{1em}` suitably.

Comment: Thank so very much for your help. That is exactly what I want. You're a good guy!

Comment: @YacineEngineering Please consider up voting (once you get 15 rep points) and accepting the most useful answer (after a certain delay, waiting for other answers). This is how thanks are appreciated in this site. For details please refer: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The wrapfigures need something to be wrapped around. If you have nothing behind your second section, you could just add an empty `\mbox` or alike.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \section{Matériaux Flexibles}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{silicon.jpg}      
        \caption{silicone}
    \end{wrapfigure}%
    \mbox{}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
        \vspace{-20pt}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{snake.jpg}
        \caption{silicone}
    \end{wrapfigure}    

    Un matériau est dit flexible s'il se déforme sous l'action d'une force extérieur 
    tel que: le silicone (figure 3.1), le caoutchouc et certains matériaux plastiques.

    La flexibilité de ces matériaux permettent des nouvelles applications dans différents domaines, notamment, la robotique et l'interface utilisateur.

    L'introduction des robots issues des matériaux douces et flexibles a augmenté la chance de leurs utilisation dans les applications où il y a nécessité d'interaction      directe avec l'homme, par exemple: dans le domaine médicale pour la chirurgie et l'interaction avec les malades (figure 3.2). De plus, ces matériaux ont joué un rôle majeur dans le développement de la biomimétisme, permettant ainsi des mouvements complexes qui ne sont pas possible à réaliser avec les robots rigides. \blindtext
    %
    \section{Retour Haptique}
    \mbox{}
\end{document}
```

[image]